# Workaround in MySQL for partial Index or filtered Index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, partial, partial-index

I am using a MySQL database. I know PostgreSQL and SQL Server supports partial indexing. In my case I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myIndex ON myTable (myColumn) where myColumn <> 'myText'
```

I want to create a unique constraint but it should allow duplicates if it is a particular text.

I couldn't find a direct way to do this in MySQL. But, is there a workaround to achieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose there is only one way to achieve it. You can add another column to your table, create index on it and create trigger or do insert/update inside your stored procedures to fill this column using following condition:

```
if value = 'myText' then put null
otherwise put value
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 23):

Filtered indexes could be emulated with function indexes and `CASE` expression(MySQL 8.0.13 and newer):

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, myColumn VARCHAR(100));

-- NULL are not taken into account with `UNIQUE` indexes   
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myIndex ON t((CASE WHEN myColumn <> 'myText' THEN myColumn END));


-- inserting excluded value twice
INSERT INTO t(id, myColumn) VALUES(1, 'myText'), (2, 'myText');

-- trying to insert different value than excluded twice
INSERT INTO t(id, myColumn) VALUES(3, 'aaaaa');

INSERT INTO t(id, myColumn) VALUES(4, 'aaaaa');
-- Duplicate entry 'aaaaa' for key 'myIndex'

SELECT * FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04e679cd84e51361dfff4e40554cbaf9)**

Output:

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | myColumn |
+-----+----------+
|  1  | myText   |
|  2  | myText   |
|  3  | aaaaa    |
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: I'd point out that doing this creates an index that separates all the rows that have `myColumn=mytext` from all the others, **BUT** the index still includes *all* the table's rows.  So you get the same index functionality as a filtered index, but you *don't* get the space savings.  If what you really want is to create an index that *efficiently* references only a very small % of a table's rows (such as, e.g. orders in-process, out of all order records in the database), you still can't do that in MySQL AFAIK.  (And by "efficiently", I mean indexing just the rows of interest).

Comment: The accepted answer (by @ravnur) was probably the best when he posted it, but this one is now the correct answer, and much better by far.

Comment: Also, if you're using MariaDB you can't (yet, as of v10.4) create a function index as in this answer, but you can create a generated virtual column and index that, which achieves exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to create a persisted generated column with the necessary condition and a add unique index on it.

Comment: Example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167552/284917