# c# Soft Delete and Unique constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hopefully this is a quick one.
I am using global query filters to enable a soft delete solution (basically I have added a **Deleted** property to all my entities).
In most cases this is fine, but I have just run into an issue.
One of my entities was soft deleted, so it exists in the table but with **Deleted** set to false and someone has tried to create another entity with the same name.

The database has thrown an error stating that a unique constraint has been violated, which refers to this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().HasIndex(m => m.Name).IsUnique();
```

As you can see, I don't want anyone to be able to create a brand with the same name, but if that brand has been soft deleted, then it should allow me.
Is it possible to set that up? Like a conditional constraint?

Here is a list of my unique constraints for context:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Attribute>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Name, m.CriterionId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().HasIndex(m => m.Name).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasIndex(m => new { m.BrandId, m.Email }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Criterion>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Name, m.CategoryId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Field>().HasIndex(m => new { m.CategoryId, m.Name, m.IsSpecification }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<FieldMap>().HasIndex(m => new { m.FeedId, m.FieldId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<BrandCategory>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.BrandId, m.CategoryId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<BrandUser>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.BrandId, m.UserId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryGroup>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.CategoryId, m.GroupId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<TheatrePlan>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.TheatreId, m.PlanId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserCategoryInterest>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.UserId, m.CategoryId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserPlanInterest>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.UserId, m.PlanId }).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTheatreInterest>().HasIndex(m => new { m.Id, m.UserId, m.TheatreId }).IsUnique();
```

Comment: *One of my entities was soft deleted, so it exists in the table but with Deleted set to false* - huh? Your deleted entity has deleted=false?

Comment: It sounds like you've made a poor choice of primary key, or you should restore the deleted entity

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492485/mysql-with-soft-deletion-unique-key-and-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Perhaps when you soft-delete something, you could rename the brand in an algorithmic fashion, say from _MyBrand_ to _MyBrand-Deleted_.  If you have an _Undelete_ capability, then you could check to see if the Unique rule is still good, and if it is, strip of the "-Deleted" part (and, if not, signal an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a normal index, that is not possible.

You could try using an index filter (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter) but that ONLY works for MS SQLServer as other providers such as MySQL don't support partial indexing (see [Workaround in mysql for partial Index or filtered Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804565/workaround-in-mysql-for-partial-index-or-filtered-index)), so it depends on your database provider.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
        .HasIndex(b => b.Name)
        .IsUnique()
        .HasFilter("[Deleted] IS NOT NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to the following.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().HasIndex(p=> new {m => m.Name, m=>m.Deleted}).IsUnique().HasFilter("[Deleted = 0]");
```

Comment: It fails :( with the error Inccorect syntax near ';' on this line `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UserTheatreInterests_Id_UserId_TheatreId] ON [UserTheatreInterests] ([Id], [UserId], [TheatreId]) WHERE [Deleted = 0];`

Comment: did you try with all entities? or only one? Try with one first and see

Comment: I tried with them all, that is the first one it creates. I will try with them individually to see if I can figure out what the issue is

Comment: Did you mean `"[Deleted] = 0"`

Comment: @r3plica I fixed a mistake in my suggestion. I hope you are using MS SQL server.

Comment: You still have a typo, it's as @CaiusJard said